# PHP Hex and Binary

Tags: php, binary, hex, crc16

I have a string in the following format: "0A1344010400010005" (hex representation)

I would need to convert this string into an array of bytes (0x0a, 0x13, 0x44, and so forth) so that these data can be used in the following function:

```
$data = $this->data;

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) {

        // 1.value right shift 8 digits (equal to divide 256)
        // 2.XOR value and incoming data, then AND 0xFF
        // 3. get an index£¨then search related index data in CRC16_TABLE
        // XOR again
        $this->value = ($this->value >> 8) ^ $this->arr[($this->value ^ $data[$i]) & 0xff];         

    }
```

`$this->value` value is `0xFFFF`. `$this->arr` is an array containing elements: `array(0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf)`.

I have done the following. Basically, this traverses the string and separates every 2 characters as hex rep per byte and convert them to binary string.

```
$data = array();
    $len = strlen($str);
    if($len % 2 == 1) $str = "0".$str;
    $len = strlen($str);
    for($i =0; $i < $len; $i=$i+2)
    {
        $data[] = hex2bin(substr($str,$i,2));
    }
    $this->data = $data;
```

It seems that it is generating result of value 0 all the time. Is there anything that I should have done?

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pack` can convert a hex string into a binary string (bytes 0x0a, 0x13, 0x44, and so forth):

```
$data = pack('H*', '0A1344010400010005');
```

After that, what you have done should work, with one minor change: `$data[$i]` is actually a string and to get the value of the corresponding byte you need `ord`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); $i++) {
    $this->value = ($this->value >> 8) ^ $this->arr[($this->value ^ ord($data[$i])) & 0xFF];         
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It helps to know that pack will help to convert to hex binary string. but, it seems that the length would need to be calculate in `strlen($data)` instead of `sizeof($data)`

Answer (score 2):

hex2bin returns a binary string, you want an integer I think. Use ord to convert the characters to int

```
$data = array();
$len = strlen($str);
if($len % 2 == 1) $str = "0".$str;
$len = strlen($str);
for($i =0; $i < $len; $i=$i+2)
{
    $data[] = ord(hex2bin(substr($str,$i,2)));
}
$this->data = $data;
```

Comment: True, a side note: PHP >= 5.4.0 needed.